# jquery ajax call for deleting a row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

How do I delete a row by just passing the id using a jquery ajax call
    this is delete.php

```
<?php

require_once('DB.class.php');
$dbconnect = new DB('schoollife', 'root', '');

$id=$_GET['chapter_id'];

$del="DELETE FROM sl_chapter WHERE chapter_id=".$id ;
$result=mysql_query($del);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "<font color='red'>record deleted successful</font>";
//echo "<BR>";
//echo "<a href='delete.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}
else {
echo "<br/>";
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} 

?>
```

this is chapter.html

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click','.delbutton',function(){ 
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete!"))
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "json",
        url: "delete.php",
        //data: info,
        success: function(){
        }
        });
        $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        }
        return false;

        });
            </script>
```

How do I delete a row by just passing the id using a jquery ajax call
i think delete query did mistake..

Comment: You need to significantly improve your question if you expect to receive an answer.  First post full code snippets, the JS, PHP and possibly the HTML.  Also provide a better description of your end goal and the problems you encounter.

Comment: this is my create.html <script>$(document).on('click','.delbutton',function(){ 
         var del_id = element.attr("id");
   var info = 'id=' + del_id;
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete!"))
   {
   $.ajax({
   type: "json",
   url: "delete.php",
   //data: info,
   success: function(){
   }
   });
   $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
   .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
   }
   return false;
     
   });
    </script>

Comment: Put this code in the question above, you can edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there, you need to pass the id you want to delete to delete.php

chapter.html:

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click','.delbutton',function(){ 
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete!"))
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST", //changed
        url: "delete.php",
        data: 'id=' + del_id, // changed
        success: function(){
        }
        });
        $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        }
        return false;

        });
            </script>
```

delete.php:

```
require_once('DB.class.php');
$dbconnect = new DB('schoollife', 'root', '');

$id=$_POST['id']; //changed

$del="DELETE FROM sl_chapter WHERE chapter_id=".$id ;
$result=mysql_query($del);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "<font color='red'>record deleted successful</font>";
//echo "<BR>";
//echo "<a href='delete.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}
else {
echo "<br/>";
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} 

?>
```

Comment: in delete.php  iam using GET method but error showing like this:   Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: if you are using GET method, then change type: "POST" in javascript to type: "GET" but your syntax error near line 1 might point to a whole different problem

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `JSON` as type in jquery but the `type` should be either `POST` or `GET`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", // should be GET or POST not JSON
    url: "delete.php",
    data: info,
    success: function(){
    }
});
```

Also change this in `delete.php`

```
$id=$_GET['chapter_id'];
```

to

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: in delete.php http://localhost/delete.php?id=19 record successfully deleted but in my chapter.html ids showing...

Comment: @user2417377 Because on success of deletion you are not hiding the deleted row.

Comment: @user2417377 But you said `sorry...in my chapter.html ids not showing..`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, couple of fixes:

1. You are sending JSON instead of GET
2. I assume that you want to execute the animation only after the delete, so place your animation inside `success`. (if not, please ignore this).
3. Don't comment out the `data`
4. replace `id` to `chapter_id` inside `info` variable

   ```
   $(document).on('click','.delbutton',function(){ 
   var del_id = element.attr("id");
   var info = 'chapter_id=' + del_id;

   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete!"))
   {
       $.ajax({
       type: "get",
       url: "delete.php",
       data: info,
       success: function(){
           $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
       }
       });
   }
   return false;
   });
   ```